# Is it possible to render specifically the icon of a Fancytree node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

In my application I have a function that visits my entire tree and then does some ajax-dependent processing to every node of a certain type (namely it adds some children to it). The entire process takes some time to run but since it's asynchronous the browser doesn't freeze up and the user could go on interacting with the nodes that had gotten the ajax response before all of the responses are done.

To that effect I am configuring `iconClass` like this:

```
iconClass: function (event, data) {
    switch (data.node.data.type) {
        case "folder":
            return "fa fa-folder";
            break;
        case "normal":
            return "fa fa-folder-o";
            break;
        case "loading":
            return "fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-pulse";
            break;
        default:
            return "fa fa-question-circle";
    }
}
```

With those icons configured, I set my `node.data.type` to "loading" before starting the ajax call for that node, and then at the `ajax.success` I re-set my `node.data.type` back to "normal". This alone does not change the node's icon if it is rendered on the screen.

I know I can achieve what I want by simply calling `node.render()` or `node.renderTitle()`, however, since I am using `ext-tree`, this also calls `renderColumns()` which is something I do not want at this point (renderColumns creates input fields and this causes me problems with my jquery-validate plugin.)

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the HTML of a fancytree node in 2 ways:

- If the HTML is located in the ".fancytree-title"-span, you can manipulate it's HTML by changing the `data.node.title`. Beware though, this is a HTML string, no DOM or JQuery object
- If you want to change some other HTML, you can manipulate the `data.node.li`. This is a DOM element. You can easily manipulate it with JQuery by using `$(node.data.li)`

Good luck